# Send result of query in email body using python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Essentially I'm trying to send the results of a query in the body of an email and can't figure it out. I tested the code for the SQL query and it works independently. I also can send an email no problem. Having trouble putting them both together. I then tried converting the result of the query into a string but that's not working. Here is my code:

```
import smtplib
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
                      r"DBQ=\\Location.accdb;")

query = """SELECT *;
        """

df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)

remail = "sendto@gmail.com"

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()

smtpObj.login('from@gmail.com','PASSWORD')

smtpObj.sendmail('from@gmail.com', remail, 'Subject: Latest Query \n' + string(df))

smtpObj.quit()'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any error message? Also, what's `string`? There's no such keyword in Python. Maybe you mean `str` or `unicode` if working with 2.x.

Comment: str doesn't work. Error is 'smtpObj.sendmail('from@gmail.com', remail, Subject: \n'dfquery)
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this -

```
smtpObj.sendmail('from@gmail.com', remail, 'Subject: Latest Query \n' + string(df))
```

to -

```
smtpObj.sendmail('from@gmail.com', remail, 'Subject: Latest Query \n' + df.to_string())
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Error: smtpObj.sendmail('from@gmail.com', remail, 'Subject: \n'dfquery)
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: There was another part interfering with my code that I didn't see but this fixes my code above. Thanks!